# Find or create a unique associated object in idiomatic ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

How do I idiomatically create a new topic if one does not exist, or create an association to conferences if the topic does exist?

I'm working on a project that has Conferences and Topics. They are both associated with each other through a ConferenceTopic object. The Topics' names are unique.

Below is the custom method I created on Conferences called `#find_or_create_topic_with` which takes an argument of name. I did this because when I tried to `#find_or_create_by` name on a conference's topic I didn't successfully make one for the second topic (Rails Console log below)

[The commit for this kludge is on Github.](https://github.com/callbackwomen/callback-women-rails/commit/8aa375ee771f6d5c2a5e5f8506cdf0077818e415)

```
class Conference < ActiveRecord::Base
  …

  def find_or_create_topic_with(name)
    if topic = Topic.find_by(name: name)
      self.topics.include?(topic) ? topic : self.topics << topic
    else
      self.topics.create(name: name)
    end
  end
end
```

**Rails Console log for find_or_create_by on topics**

```
2.1.2 :001 > Conference.last.topics.find_or_create_by(name: "fun")
  Conference Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "conferences".* FROM "conferences"   ORDER BY "conferences"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  Topic Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "topics".* FROM "topics" INNER JOIN "conference_topics" ON "topics"."id" = "conference_topics"."topic_id" WHERE "conference_topics"."conference_id" = $1 AND "topics"."name" = 'fun' LIMIT 1  [["conference_id", 3]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Topic Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "topics"  WHERE "topics"."name" = 'fun' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "topics" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2014-08-31 18:57:56.274109"], ["name", "fun"], ["updated_at", "2014-08-31 18:57:56.274109"]]
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "conference_topics" ("conference_id", "created_at", "topic_id", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["conference_id", 3], ["created_at", "2014-08-31 18:57:56.287526"], ["topic_id", 8], ["updated_at", "2014-08-31 18:57:56.287526"]]
   (2.1ms)  COMMIT
 => #<Topic id: 8, name: "fun", created_at: "2014-08-31 18:57:56", updated_at: "2014-08-31 18:57:56">
2.1.2 :002 > Conference.first.topics.find_or_create_by(name: "fun")
  Conference Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "conferences".* FROM "conferences"   ORDER BY "conferences"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Topic Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "topics".* FROM "topics" INNER JOIN "conference_topics" ON "topics"."id" = "conference_topics"."topic_id" WHERE "conference_topics"."conference_id" = $1 AND "topics"."name" = 'fun' LIMIT 1  [["conference_id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Topic Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "topics"  WHERE "topics"."name" = 'fun' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
 => #<Topic id: nil, name: "fun", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
2.1.2 :003 > Conference.first.topics
  Conference Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "conferences".* FROM "conferences"   ORDER BY "conferences"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Topic Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "topics".* FROM "topics" INNER JOIN "conference_topics" ON "topics"."id" = "conference_topics"."topic_id" WHERE "conference_topics"."conference_id" = $1  [["conference_id", 1]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Topic id: 7, name: "ruby", created_at: "2014-08-31 18:40:40", updated_at: "2014-08-31 18:40:40">]>
```

**Below is the log for finding the conferences for a the topic "fun"**

```
2.1.2 :015 > Topic.find_by(name: "fun").conferences
  Topic Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "topics".* FROM "topics"  WHERE "topics"."name" = 'fun' LIMIT 1
  Conference Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "conferences".* FROM "conferences" INNER JOIN "conference_topics" ON "conferences"."id" = "conference_topics"."conference_id" WHERE "conference_topics"."topic_id" = $1  [["topic_id", 8]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Conference id: 3, name: "TooLongDidn'tCareConf", location: "Boston", code_of_conduct: false, childcare: false, last_years_attendance: 0, created_at: "2014-08-31 17:47:35", updated_at: "2014-08-31 17:47:35">]>
2.1.2 :016 > Topic.find_by(name: "fun").conferences.count
  Topic Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "topics".* FROM "topics"  WHERE "topics"."name" = 'fun' LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "conferences" INNER JOIN "conference_topics" ON "conferences"."id" = "conference_topics"."conference_id" WHERE "conference_topics"."topic_id" = $1  [["topic_id", 8]]
 => 1
```

I would like the collection proxy to contain both the first and last conferences, and the count to be 2. With just `#find_or_create_by` I can only associate it with the conference it is first created for, not subsequent conferences which find the topic with an id of nil.

Answer (score 2):

Just having read over the code, it looks like you're trying to satisfy three use cases:

- The topic exists and is already joined to the conference. => Do nothing.
- The topic exists and is not joined to the conference. => Add the topic to the conference's topics.
- The topic does not exist. => Create the topic and add it to the conference's topics.

I think your code is fine. Really. There is nothing too gross about it where I would immediately want to rewrite it.

That said, I would probably have written it like this:

```
def find_or_create_topic_with(name)
  transaction do
    topic = Topic.where(name: name).first_or_create!
    self.topics.where(topic: topic).first_or_create!
  end
rescue
  # need to handle uniqueness violations, etc.
end
```

Some additional notes:

- Where's  the tests, bro!?
- To avoid race conditions creating bad data, you probably want a unique index on topics for name (never have a validates_uniqueness in a model without a unique index to back it up!) and another on conference topics for topic_id and conference_id.

Feel free to hit me up on twitter or whatever if any of this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Conference has_many Topics. Given that, you should just be able to use [`find_or_create_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by) on the `.topics` relation:

```
topic = my_conference.topics.find_or_create_by(name: "Name")

# topic will now contain either a newly created Topic that is associated with `my_conference`,
# or will be the existing Topic with name "Name" from `my_conference.topics`.
```

Comment: Checkout the console log above. It successfully _creates_ a topic, but the find (The second use) seems short circuited. Maybe I need to be find_or_creating a ConferenceTopic, but it seems kludgier to manipulate the join object.

Comment: If topic names are globally unique then you don't want to use "my_conference.topics" as it will create another topic as long as there's no topic with that name associated with the given conference.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read through the whole console at first, but I have now. However, I don't see what the problem is. After creating a topic with a given name, the second attempt with `find_or_create` by that same name *should* short-circuit and nothing new should be created. So what am I missing?

Comment: Michael> That makes a lot of sense. What's a better way to write it so that I can associate the globally unique topics with conferences. Should I be find_or_creating off of the ConferenceTopic?

Comment: pdobb> I have updated to more clearly indicate the code that I want.